# Hosting/transferring a web site on Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, web, web-hosting

I have my website currently hosted on paid server, but i want to transfer it on GAE.
How can i do it? Can anyone please help me in this case.I'd appreciate your help.
Thanks:)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

1) First you will have to adapt your website to the GAE framework (python with django or the new Java environment). You can test your work by [downloading the SDK](http://code.google.com/appengine/downloads.html) of GAE which offer a local server.

2) Then create an account on [appengine.google.com](http://appengine.google.com/) and upload your application on something.appspot.com, test it.

3) If you have a domain name, create a google apps account on this domain, and finally bind this domain with your GAE website. [Here](http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/domains.html) is the Google doc.

Answer (score 11):

If it is just a static website which does not need server side scripts or a database, then you might want to look into Google Sites instead of Appengine.  You can find out more about Sites here: http://www.google.com/sites/help/intl/en/overview.html

If you do have some server side logic going on, you will need to convert it to either python or java and convert your relational database to Google's Data API which does not support the SQL your current database uses.  You can read more about the APIs and what is supported with the Data API and tutorials at: http://code.google.com/appengine/

Comment: Actually, it's generated html and not plain html. and google appengine is for static data... right?

Comment: Google Sites is for mostly static content, you can jazz it up with widgets.

Google AppEngine is a full fledged application.  It gives you much the same functionality as php+mysql, but the technologies are different.  You can host only a static website on it as well, but you can do more.

Comment: So in your case, since the html is generated, you want to use AppEngine.

Answer (score 4):

In response to sanorita's comment "*Actually, it's generated html and not plain html. and google appengine is for static data... right?*":

AppEngine can host static data, but that is far from its intent.

The purpose of AppEngine is to allow developers to easily deploy their dynamic applications on Google's infrastructure. In the end, assuming you have programmed your app in effective ways to handle scaling (*basically just noting that writes to the database are expensive, and contention is the root of all evil*) you can handle nearly any amount of traffic.